# how the page content will reload after ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to reload only the page content, not the whole page after  jquery ajax success function for the given  php and javascript code. In that initially it displays

> success

and after ajax call it will display as

> failed

with reloading the whole page..

Php code :

```
 <?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$sql="select * from tbl_status where id='1'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
if($row['status']=='1')
{
 ?>
Success <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">0</div>
 <?php
 }
 else
 {
 ?>
 Failed
<div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">1</div>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 <input type="submit" class="send"/>
```

Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.send').click(function(){
var status=$('.status').text();
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST', 
       url: 'http://localhost/status/updatestatus.php',
           data: 'status='+status,
         success  : function (e)
         {
           var response=e;
           alert(response);

         },
         error: function()
         {
         alert('error');
         }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: you want to realod the page ?? or you don't want to.. this is confusing...

Comment: i dont want to reload the whole page, only reloading the page content

Comment: ok fine.. then why are you using location.reload() ?? .. can you tell us where you want to put the content ??

Comment: when i click the submit button, the status column in the database table  will change to '0' and the result is displaying as an alert, then how the 'success' is change to 'failed' without reloading the whole page

Answer (score 1):

Try.Sorry for if there are some issues as it was written in notepad.

index.php

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$sql="select * from tbl_status where id='1'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
<div id="response">
if($row['status']=='1')
{
?>
   Success <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">0</div>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
Failed
<div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">1</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="send"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.send').click(function(){
  var status=$('.status').text();
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST', 
       url: 'http://localhost/status/updatestatus.php',
           data: 'status='+status,
         success  : function (data, status)
         {
           $("#response").html(data.status);
         },
         error: function()
         {
           alert('error');
         }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

updatestatus.php

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$sql="update tbl_status set status=$_POST['status'] where id='1'";    
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_affected_rows();

if($count > 0){
    return json_encode(array('status'=>$count));
}else{
    return json_encode(array('status'=>0));
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

If you are  having problem with reloading the page then you can use

`window.location.href=window.location.href;`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

considering your ajax is working fine... and the response you are getting is HTML

you don't need to call location.reload()..
you just need to append the response to the DOMtree..

**updated**

**HTML**

```
....
?>  //close php tag
<div id="displayStatus">  //create new div with id displayStatus
<?php
if($row['status']=='1')
{
 ?>
    Success <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">0</div>
<?php
 }
 else{
 ?>
    Failed <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">1</div>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
 </div> //end the div
```

**JQUERY**

```
success  : function (e)
     {
       var response=e;
       alert(response);
       $('#displayStatus').html(response); //replace the content in that
     },
```

**updatestatus.php**

```
 $status= $_POST['status'];
//make you query ..update your table 
 if($status == '0'){
     echo 'Failed <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">1</div>';
 }else{
    echo 'Success <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden;">0</div>';
 }
```

Comment: ya, problem is there, it want to  display 'success' when status='1' and display 'failed' when status='0'.
SO, when we are updating status='0' using ajax, the 'success' will change to 'failed' after ajax success function without reloading the whole page, only reloading the page content..

Answer (score 0):

use load instead reload in your success

```
...
 success  : function (e)
     {
       $('your id or class name').load(php_file_name +'your_id_or_class_to_refresh');
       var response=e;
       alert(response);
       location.reload();
     },
....


// location.reload(); // <-- does not work so
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: your jQuery part and your PHP part are not compatible.
You didn't really change your return status, just text. To signal "Failed" use some header on PHP side. For example:

in PHP:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
die('Failed');
```

Then you ajax will raise an "error" handler instead of "success".

**OR** you should use only "success" handler and test returned text in in:

in JavaScript:

```
success: function(data) {
   if (data == 'Failed') {
       alert('ERROR');
       location.reload();
   } else {
        alert('Success');
   } 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to change the status and show the changed value on the page.  This is a Javascript function that uses an Ajax request to PHP that changes the value of status in the database.

```
function changeStatus(divID,id,action,frontOrAdmin)
{


        xmlhttp=getobject();
        var query="id="+id+"&action="+action+"&frontOrAdmin="+frontOrAdmin;
        $oldStatus = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML='<img src="images/loading_icon.gif">';
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
                {
                        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        var responseArr = response.split(",");

                        if(($.trim(responseArr[1])=="0")||($.trim(responseArr[1])=="1")){
                           document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=responseArr[0];
                        }
                        else{           
                            alert(responseArr[0]);
                            document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=$oldStatus;
                        }
                }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","pass.php?type=changestatus&"+query,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null); 
}
```